# Getting KeyError while creating a client for Google’s Maps API using urllib, urllib2 and json modules

Tags: python, json, urllib2

```
import urllib,urllib2
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
params = {'q': '207 N. Defiance St, Archbold, OH','output': 'json', 'oe': 'utf8'}
url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?' + urllib.urlencode(params)

rawreply = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
reply = json.loads(rawreply)
print (reply['Placemark'][0]['Point']['coordinates'][:-1])
```

On executing this code i m getting an error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Foundations_of_networking/search2.py", line 11, in 
    print (reply['Placemark'][0]['Point']['coordinates'][:-1])
KeyError: 'Placemark'

If anyone knows the solution kindly help me. I'm just new to python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print just `reply` you'll see this:

```
{u'Status': {u'code': 610, u'request': u'geocode'}}
```

You are using a deprecated version of the API. Move to v3. Take a look at the notice at the top of [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/).

I haven't used this API before but the following tipped me off (taken from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodingupgrade)):

> New endpoint
>
> The v3 Geocoder uses a different URL endpoint:
>
> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters Where
>   output can be specified as json or xml.
>
> Developers switching from v2 may be using a legacy hostname — either
>   maps.google.com, or maps-api-ssl.google.com if using SSL. You should
>   migrate to the new hostname: maps.googleapis.com. This hostname can be
>   used both over both HTTPS and HTTP.

Try the following:

```
import urllib,urllib2
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
params = {'address': '207 N. Defiance St, Archbold, OH', 'sensor' : 'false', 'oe': 'utf8'}
url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?' + urllib.urlencode(params)

rawreply = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
reply = json.loads(rawreply)

if reply['status'] == 'OK':
    #supports multiple results
    for item in reply['results']:
        print (item['geometry']['location'])

    #always chooses first result
    print (reply['results'][0]['geometry']['location'])
else:
    print (reply)
```

Above I've shown two ways to access the longitude and latitude for the result. The `for` loop will support the situation in which multiple results are returned. The second simply chooses the first result. Notice that in either case, I first check the `status` of the return to make sure real data came back.

If you want to access the latitude and longitude independently you can do so like this:

```
# in the for loop
lat = item['geometry']['location']['lat']
lng = item['geometry']['location']['lng']

# in the second approach
lat = reply['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
lng = reply['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
```

Comment: @ Brian..Above code is working .. but if i just want to see  latitude and longitude..then what changes i have to do in above code.

Comment: @user2433888 I've updated the answer to show accessing the coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Just print out raw reply, see what keys it has and then access the keys, if you do:

```
print (reply["Status"]),
```

you'll get:

```
{u'code': 610, u'request': u'geocode'}
```

and your whole JSON looks like this:

```
{u'Status': {u'code': 610, u'request': u'geocode'}}
```

so if you want to access code just do:

```
print(reply["Status"]["code"])
```

Comment: @Pawelmhm... if i just want to see latitude and longitude..then what changes i have to do in above code.

Answer (score 0):

A KeyError exception raises when you are trying to access to a key that it's no present on the object.

I print the response text in rawreply:

```
>>> print rawreply
... {
      "Status": {
        "code": 610,
        "request": "geocode"
      }
    }
```

So the problem it's that you are not receiving the expected response, there it's no 'Placemark' key in there, so therefore the exception.

Look for what's the meaning of code 610 on Google Maps API, maybe you're not making the correct query or you have to check the response before access it.